# Installing the RoR stack in ubuntu 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is setting up ruby on rails in ubuntu (for a ubuntu beginner) like getting a root canal at the dentist's office?

First of all downloading ruby, rubygems and rails itself takes forever with so many commands... Then, apparently there's already Ruby 1.8.7 in ubuntu - and when I try to install ruby 1.9.2 (for rails 3) it goes somewhere else... and rails doesn't see the new ruby...

Ugg...

Comment: From your question, I see no reason you *should* use RVM (although you certainly could).  You should use RVM if you want to test your app on multiple versions of ruby, however.

Comment: **Do not** use apt-get to install Ruby. Ever. Quote: *Under no circumstance should you install Ruby, Rubygems or any Ruby-related packages from apt-get. This system is out-dated and leads to major headaches. Avoid it for Ruby-related packages. We do Ruby, we know what's best. Trust us* (Ryan Bigg's post)

Comment: Yea I'm not sure I need that level of coolness yet :) I just want to be able to get one version of ruby and one version of rails and just play with it already lol... will try Your reccomendation Cam. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryan Bigg has an excellent post about this using RVM.  For setting up rails, you generally want to avoid installation via aptitude.

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you

Answer (score 0):

I had to (not sure if this is standard), Download rails/ruby offline and link it to my bin folder before everything was good, I also had to go remove all the old stuff ubuntu flung at me. Quite painful I wish ubuntu would just update the repositories to point to the 1.9.2.

Comment: Scratch this, RVM is much better as a solution can't believe I spaced that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full rubygems1.9.1 # this is really 1.9.2 despite the confusing name
$ export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin:$PATH # add this to your ~/.bashrc too
$ sudo gem1.9.1 install rails
$ rails new foo_project
```

enjoy.

Comment: Do **not** use apt-get to install Ruby. Ever.

Comment: @cam, I speak from my experience and so advised accordingly (maybe I should have added "IMO"). That said, I believe it is far better to use a tool that is meant specifically for the purpose and is kept up-to-date rather than rely on the OS's package manager. Final decision of what direction to take is of course is whatever one's self thinks is right :)

Comment: @Zabba, I'm OK with you having that opinion.  I wonder what the boundaries of your fear of package-management are.  Do you build your own database and web servers?

Comment: @n0chi, I just realized installing ruby1.9.1-full will only pull in rubygems if you have apt configured to pull in suggested packages.  I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: So i've made a total mess of this :) Is there a way to remove rails 3? (I have a couple of rails and a couple of rubygems installed lol)

Comment: @n0chi.  that is a good question.  You can do `gem1.9.1 uninstall rails` to uninstall the version of rails that you installed with the packaged rubygems.  You'll have to run that command for any other versions of rubygems you have installed as well.  What exactly is going wrong at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I agree about the root canal feeling. I wrote a script that does the setup for me. You can find it here: https://github.com/sleepycat/wrong-side-of-the-tracks

Suggestions, bug fixes and improvements welcome.

Comment: Is there something like this for the mac as well?

Comment: It's certainly possible but I wouldn't know. FYI I'm going to be updating that script shortly to use RVM.